# warning: ISO C++98 does not support the ‘z’ gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]

Tags: 16.04, gcc, make, tools, gnu

I'm new in the "ubuntu community", I've just started a project with my university where I need to install a toolchain (the **OpenRisc GNU toolchain** from this tutorial: https://github.com/kdgwill/OR1K/wiki/OpenRisc-tools-Install) but I faced this problem.

When I need to build gcc with the *make* command (**build GCC - stage 1**) the process doesn't finish and continues to show the message reported in the title referring to the argument of the *fprintf*, function present inside many files inside the or1k-gcc directory. It doesn't terminate, it only continues to running showing this:

```
g++ -fno-PIE -c  -DIN_GCC_FRONTEND -g -O2 -DIN_GCC-DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE
-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall
-Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual 
-pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings 
-fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ic-family -I../../or1k-gcc/gcc -I../../or1k-gcc/gcc/c-family 
-I../../or1k-gcc/gcc/../include -I../../or1k-gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include  -I../../or1k-gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../or1k-gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../../or1k-gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o c-family/c-dump.o -MT 
c-family/c-dump.o -MMD -MP -MF c-family/.deps/c-dump.TPo ../../or1k-gcc/gcc/c-family/c-dump.c
In file included from ../../or1k-gcc/gcc/hash-table.h:561:0,
                 from ../../or1k-gcc/gcc/coretypes.h:440,
                 from ../../or1k-gcc/gcc/c-family/c-dump.c:23:
../../or1k-gcc/gcc/mem-stats.h: In member function ‘void mem_usage::dump(mem_location*, mem_usage&) const’:
../../or1k-gcc/gcc/mem-stats.h:213:72: warning: ISO C++98 does not support the ‘z’ gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]
       get_percent (m_times, total.m_times), loc->m_ggc ? "ggc" : "heap");
                                                                        ^
../../or1k-gcc/gcc/mem-stats.h:213:72: warning: ISO C++98 does not support the ‘z’ gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]
../../or1k-gcc/gcc/mem-stats.h:213:72: warning: ISO C++98 does not support the ‘z’ gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]
../../or1k-gcc/gcc/mem-stats.h: In member function ‘void mem_usage::dump_footer() const’:
../../or1k-gcc/gcc/mem-stats.h:224:55: warning: ISO C++98 does not support the ‘z’ gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]
       SIZE_AMOUNT (m_allocated), SIZE_AMOUNT (m_times));
                                                       ^
../../or1k-gcc/gcc/mem-stats.h:224:55: warning: ISO C++98 does not support the ‘z’ gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]
```

Following forums or tutorials I've tried to update the gcc compiler as someone says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378969/how-to-change-gcc-compiler-to-c11-on-ubuntu) but nothing changes.

Thanks to all those who will try to help me :)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for clarifying it I'll edit the question. Anyway 'make' doesn't terminate, it takes too long and the two commands you suggested me to run return me this:

`Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition 5252092 135808 -1`

-------------

              `total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           4,9G        2,2G        317M        155M        2,3G        2,2G
Swap:          5,0G        132M        4,9G`

Comment: My RAM is a 4.9G ram, type DDR3

Comment: The output of `swapon -s` and `free -h` is hard to read in your comment. You can **[edit]** it into your question. You can also check their output when `make` *isn't* running (for comparison) and install `iotop` and run it while `make` runs to see disk usage. I suspected the build ran out of memory and was swapping. Based on the info in your comment, I'm not so sure. Does it repeat the *exact* same messages, with the same filenames and line numbers, including the same `.c` file under "In file included from," or just the same warning? Did you try deleting the `OR1K` directory and starting over?

Comment: @EliahKagan you're right, the output I reported is not so clear. Anyway before trying to delete and rebuild the directory I found [here](https://openrisc.io/newlib/multicore.html) the same toolchain but pre-compiled. It should be the same, shouldn't it? Also I'd like to ask you if I need to do something about it or I only need to download it. Thank you again.